How to add CPT in Elementor pro search template
i have created a Search  template in elementor pro, i'm using Archive Posts widget to show the result.
but the problem is i want to include the CPT in the result.
i tried the pre get post function, but its not working, it only shows the posts

function vikram_include_custom_post_types_in_search_results( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'service', 'specialty' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'vikram_include_custom_post_types_in_search_results', 10, 1 );

plz guide me how to do this
thanks in advance

You'll have to ask Elementor Pro; I don't even know if their Archive Posts Widget has this capability.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
